# How long can an account be inactive for?

Tags: support, user-accounts

By inactive I mean not logged-in by the User.

I am asking this question because, I answered one or two OLD questions (3yrs old) hoping that he/she will try my solution and reply if not accepting.  But I see nothing.  No up-votes or down-votes or comments.

So, Is there any way I can know whether he/she is an active member?And Will the accounts get deleted (with their posts) if its not used for a long time?

Comment: I don't know about inactive accounts but you can look at anyones profile and on the right it says `Last seen`, this is when the user last interacted with the site.

Comment: There is no reason to expect the OP to answer/vote/comment. Anyone can do it and as soon as you answer, the question is put on the front page again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48262/270345):

> Accounts which are deemed to be abandoned will be deleted, and the
>   user information on their questions and answers will be denormalized
>   into text fields.
>
> Cookie-based unregistered accounts will be deleted when:
>
> 1. The user has not visited the site in six months
>
>    **AND**
> 2. The user has less than 50 reputation.
>
> OpenID registered accounts will be deleted when:
>
> 1. The user has not visited the site in six months
>
>    **AND**
> 2. The user has only 1 reputation (i.e. has never received an upvote)

Comment: Thanks :) , But an "OpenID registered account" with more than 1 vote will never be deleted even if it is not used by the user anymore.?? @muru

Comment: @SeverusTux Here's one that's been hanging around for 5 years: http://askubuntu.com/users/21/geod